# Javascript / Ajax Refresh Function not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

So it loads fine and displays the meter bar perfectly but it does not refresh on the interval that I set it to. Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

```
function KBartbar(){

  <?php $artcount= KB::countArtDaily();?>

  document.getElementById("artbarcount").innerHTML='<span style="cursor:pointer" class="progressbar artbar"><?php echo $artcount;?><span>';

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".artbar").progressBar({ textFormat: 'false'});
  });
}

setInterval('KBartbar();', 3000);
```

Comment: This code works, but PHP is not regenerated. You are misunderstanding client-side and server-side code. You should implements AJAX for this task.

Comment: Ah gotcha, so i need to make a PHP page that is pulled into it. I have another function like this but a little different . Ill give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setInterval(KBartbar, 3000);
```

function name should be enough

Comment: That won't work. The code is never refreshed. AJAX needs to be used to achieve what he wants....

Comment: Oh, yes, yes. I've missed it. Sorry:) That code is a mass of JS and PHP. Why it is tagged `ajax`? People event don't know what does mean 'ajax' exactly but they sound about it everywhere. @Luke Nothing personal.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language.  To do what you want and repeatedly get $artcount, you need to use an Ajax request to grab the data asynchronously to use in your javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp is a great tutorial to get started (if you don't already know how to use Ajax).